# How to tell if the current language is written RTL or LTR

Tags: theming, i18n-l10n

I'm looking for the function – if that exists – for asking Drupal about the current language direction (RTL/LTR).

I check the global language variable but it doesn't contain that information.

Answer (score 1):

After looking more closely into $GLOBALS['language'] I found it actually has the language direction, so the answer is:

```
global $language;
if($language->direction == 1)
    echo 'RTL';
else /* $language->direction == 0 */
    echo 'LTR';
```

Better yet — thank you [MPD](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/72915/how-to-tell-if-the-current-language-is-written-rtl-or-ltr#comment80096_72917), I can use the Drupal constants [LANGUAGE_LTR](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_LTR) and [LANGUAGE_RTL](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!bootstrap.inc/constant/LANGUAGE_RTL) instead of 0 and 1 respectively, just like this:

```
global $language;
if($language->direction == LANGUAGE_RTL)
    echo 'RTL';
else /* $language->direction == LANGUAGE_LTR */
    echo 'LTR';
```

For reference this is what `$GLOBALS['language']` looks like:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [language] => ar
    [name] => Arabic
    [native] => 'Arabic' [it was in arabic letters but SE refused it]
    [direction] => 1
    [enabled] => 1
    [plurals] => 0
    [formula] => 
    [domain] => 
    [prefix] => ar
    [weight] => 0
    [javascript] => 
    [provider] => language-default
)
```

Comment: Instead of using `0` and `1`, you should use `LANGUAGE_LTR` and `LANGUAGE_RTL`.  See includes/bootstrap.inc

Comment: Regarding, the `native` property.  We had to ban the entire Arabic unicode block b/c of some very persistent spammers.  If this becomes a problem with legit posts to DA, flag a post and we will see what we can do.